# The program for LEDs 8x8 doesn't function in Arduino Uno. I'm not using the pinMode() method. I'm using the other method for specification

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno, led

The program for LEDs 8x8 doesn't function in Arduino Uno. I'm not using the pinMode() method to specify pin OUTPUT for LEDs. I'm using the method  "LedControl"

The specification pin:

```
"lc=LedControl(4,6,5,1);"
```

**for setting the pin. Why ?**

> 1. This program compiles and executes without problems.
> 2. I'm importing the library correctly.
> 3. I'm using this example:

```
#include "LedControl.h"
/*Now we need a LedControl to work with.
pin 4 is connected to the DataIn
pin 5 is connected to the CLK
pin 6 is connected to LOAD / CS
We only have a single MAX7219 */
LedControl lc=LedControl(4,6,5,1);
/* we always wait a bit between updates of the display */
unsigned long delaytime=500;
void setup() {
  /* The MAX72XX is in power-saving mode on startup,
  we have to do a wakeup call */
  lc.shutdown(0,false);
  lc.setIntensity(0,8);
  lc.clearDisplay(0);
}
void loop() {
  lc.setIntensity(0,8);
  single();
  lc.clearDisplay(0);
}
        
/* This function will light up every Led on the matrix. The led will blink along with the row-number. row number 4 (index==3) will blink 4 times etc. */
void single() {
  for(int row=0;row<8;row++) {
    for(int col=0;col<8;col++) {
      delay(50);
      lc.setLed(0,row,col,true);
      delay(50);
      for(int i=0;i<col;i++) {
        lc.setLed(0,row,col,false);
        delay(50);
        lc.setLed(0,row,col,true);
        delay(50);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this belong in the [Arduino community](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Story. Problems for formatting this code block using the tool of browser.

Comment: What is your desired outcome?

Comment: Great question title!

Comment: It provides plenty of detail, indeed.

Comment: I could fix formatting :-)

Comment: So is your issue that you're using this library, and it's compiling, but your LED pins aren't turning on?

Comment: Hi Dodo. flashes an LED in each row by column at a time covering the whole LED matrix

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The pins are linking yes. For other method tested with the same pin configuration. But the other program I've tested I espefiquei with "pinMode ()". It would be more interesting to me.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is to make each LED flashes each row and column, one at a time. 16 LEDs will flash one at a time. This program compiles correctly and I can send to the Arduino. Also checked the connection pins again. Thanks for Help!

Comment: Are you using 64 LEDs and only 16 of them are working as expected?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: I'm Changing the pin for PWM and it is  running. Thanks so Much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LedControl` library uses `pinMode` in the background to make the LEDs easier to control. When you give values to LedControl, it automatically uses pinMode, which operates as `pinMode(pin, OUTPUT|INPUT)`.

Comment: Thank You. You Help for solve my problem. i will be better writting title questions.